# How to update specific field only if its previous value is not null, out of multiple fields

Tags: postgresql

I'm updating a, b, c, d values along with where condition where id being compared. I need to update field 'b' only if its previous value is not null.
I need to update remaining fields though, In the same query.

my current query is like

```
update demo_table set a='str1', b='str2', c=112, d='str3' where id=191;
```

can anyone suggest a way to achieve this. Thanks in adavance.postgre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a CASE condition to your SET clause:

```
UPDATE demo_table
SET
  a = 'str1',
  b = CASE b IS NOT NULL WHEN true THEN 'str2' ELSE NULL END,
  c = 112,
  d = 'str3'
WHERE id = 191;
```